# Local DNS not resolving when connected to work VPN on Windows 11

Tags: windows, vpn, domain, local

I have an issue on Windows 11 that I haven't had on Windows 10.

When I connect to my work VPN I can't reach my home servers that are on the same subnet as my pc via domain names.

If I use ping "domain name" from cmd, I can ping these servers but when I use nslookup I can see that it tries to contact the DNS server through the VPN tunnel. That doesn't respond by design.

My servers' domain names are FQDN-s with normal country TLD (not .local) and I have the DNS entries in my router for local use and for some of my servers I have them set at the domain registrar the only difference being the IP addresses.

Without VPN everything works fine but when I'm using VPN I can't even access my other workplace's e-mails because it cannot find the OWA server.

Changing the adapter order in ncpa.cpl -> Special -> Special doesn't resolve the issue.

Again, this all worked on Windows 10 without a problem.
What could I do in this situation?

*Edit: I'm using FortiClient VPN 7.0.10.0538*

Comment: What kind of VPN do you use?

Comment: Ping and nslookup resolve DNS addresses differently. Ping uses the system resolver, and nslookup uses its own DNS client. The fact that you can ping a local server by name, suggests everything is fine. When using nslookup you would need to use the `server <dns server IP>` command to change what DNS server nslookup uses. In this case, it is probably defaulting to the remote DNS server, whereas ping is able to query multiple DNS servers configured on the system until it finds an answer. This doesn’t appear to be a DNS or routing issue and that might be distracting you from the real problem.

Comment: Please update your question with details about the VPN client you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are pinging the public IP of your local server through their publicly exposed interface (As you mentioned you're pinging their cached domain name):

it is possible that your VPN capture all traffic through the tunnel, directly from your client to the Corp VPN deamon.
And then you would be coming back from Corp Network to your home server.

It would explain why you can't contact your gateway's DNS.

This would be a config of the VPN server or client you might not be able to modify the setting without admin privileges on the client/server.
Then it is a coincidence that it happened during your OS migration.

(sorry can't comment yet)

Comment: Ping resolves the local IP from the domain name because of the router's static DNS but nslookup does not.

I had another colleague facing the same issue and he migrated to win 11 way before I did.